# Removing the last element of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, lastindexof

I'm new to Java and I'm stuck with an exercise I've been trying to solve for over a week now and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I need to delete the last elements of an ArrayList, an integer in this case.

The problem is that when I run the test, it still returns the old values.

```
public static void removeLastOccurrence(int x, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
       list.remove(list.size()-1);
    }
}
```

I also tried using **list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(x));**

But it still returns the same list when I run this test.

```
public class UTest{
    @Test
    public void testMultipleLast() {
        ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(1,1,3,5,7,1,5,9,1));
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(1,1,3,5,7,1,5,9));
        Solution.removeLastOccurence(1, input);
        assertEquals(result, input);
    }
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help and tell me what I'm missing as it's getting quite frustrating as I've the feeling that I'm just missing a small piece of the puzzle.

Comment: where you try to remove your element? i dont see any remove ?

Comment: Refer to the [`ArrayList` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), especially [`remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)).

Comment: your test should call the method you are testing right?!

Comment: list.get(list.size()-1) is not removing anything, it returns the last  element

Comment: before calling `assertEquals()`, you have to call `removeLastOccurrence(1, input);`

Comment: Also removeLastOccurrence`()` does not use the first parameter, probably you would need to use the `lastIndexOf()` method on the list to find the index of the element you want to remove

Comment: @toongeorges Yes, true. I deleted that line of code as someone recommended me that because now I'm not getting an assertion error but it states that 'Solution cannot be resolved'.

Comment: Is the name of the class on which the static method `removeLastOccurrence()` is defined `Solution`?  Are you importing this class with an import statement?

Comment: I found the issue which was pretty stupid. I started my program with package solution; and therefore it didn't work correctly. Now it's working but I'm only missing one corner case, whereas it might be possible that the code is not working for a certain integer.

Answer (score 2):

Your test should be like below. In the test code in the original post, you are not actually invoking the method that you are trying to test.

```
public class UTest
{
  @Test
  public void testMultipleLast() {
     ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(1,1,3,5,7,1,5,9,1));
     ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(1,1,3,5,7,1,5,9));

     // int x = ?
     ArrayList<Integer> actual = SomeClass.removeLastOccurrence(x, input)
     assertEquals(result, actual);
  }
 }
```

and the `removeLastOccurrence()` method can do the following

```
if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: There was one more line which I deleted because it returned an error and someone recommended me to delete it (which you can see in my original post). But as far as I know I don't have to change the Test code as it's just to see whether the code is right or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use :

```
list.remove(list.size()-1);
```

And return your new list so you can use :

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> removeLastOccurrence(int x, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
       list.remove(list.size()-1);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not removing any elements.

```
list.get(list.size()-1);
```

does not remove elements.

use

`list.remove(list.size()-1)`

instead.

Comment: Yes, true. Typo I guess. Remove doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java ArrayList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) with `get(int index)` method you just obtain the element in `index` position in your ArrayList.
This is the method you are looking for:

```
public static void removeLastOccurrence(int x, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        list.remove(list.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you pass your list as argument to the method it becomes a local variable. Therefore you are not removing the element from your `input` list but only from the local variable `list`. The solution is to `return` that local list from your method or to `remove` the element directly from your "input" list using the same code. The x parameter in your original method is unnecessary.

Comment: This is simply not true. The reference to the object is passed as value, but the properties of the object *itself* can still be changed. Changes to `input`, are reflected to both `input` and `list`.

Comment: @mc-emperor I agree that changes on `input` will be reflected on both, but not the oposite. Changes on `list` are just local to the `removeLastOccurrence` method. That's why, in this case, the `input` array is still the same after the call to `removeLastOccurrence` method.

Comment: They are both changed, since both variables refer to the same object. Changes on `list` are **not** local to the `removeLastOccurrence` method. See [the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), especially the section "Passing Reference Data Type Arguments".

Comment: Reference type tricks! Thank you. I should have tested and check the code of the "edited" question (instead of assuming it was still not working) because it actually works the way it is now.